# Why we can solve this equation in two ways with two diffrent anwser?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is this:

Find a number at the result of multiplication of it with it's next number equals the  result of multiplication of it with it's previous number.

So, It's clear that the anwser is 0:

$0×(-1)$ = $0×1$

We can prove this with this equation:
$x(x+1)$ = $x(x-1)$
Here we can do two things:

A) $x.x+x$ = $x.x-x$

$2x=0$

$x=0$

B) we have x in both sides so we can delete it: $x-1$ = $x+1$

$-1$ = $1$

So Am I wrong with solving second one? Or both are correct?

Comment: As you said in your first try, $x$ may be $0$. So if you delete it (as you do in your second try), you basically divide by $0$, which is wrong. Thus the wrong result that $1=-1$.

Comment: Quite generally, when you have an answer (like $0$ in your question) and a "proof" that no answer exists, you should plug your answer into the proof. That will usually show you the error. In your question, the proof goes from an equation $x(x+1)=x(x-1)$ that's true when $x=0$ to an equation $x+1=x-1$ that's false when $x=0$. So something must be wrong with that "delete $x$" step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second approach you are dividing by $x$, not "delete it".  You need to make sure $x$ is not $0$.  A careful approach would be to try $x=0$ and find it is a solution, then to look for others by assuming $x \neq 0$ and dividing by it.  When you reach the final contradiction it show there are no solutions except $0$.